# How to prevent flickering during postback on IE9

Tags: asp.net, postback, internet-explorer-9, flicker

I have couple of dropdownlist controls in my page which have onselectedindexchanged events. When I change my selection, a postback will occur, which will cause flickering on IE9, not on firefox. I found a way to stop the flickering on IE by using:

meta http-equiv="Page-Enter" content="Alpha(opacity=100)"

But it didn't work on IE9. Can anybody suggest a way to stop the flickering on IE9 during postback?

Answer (score 0):

You can put your controls in an Updatepanel, that way the entire page won't have to reload and no flickering will happen.

Comment: Is there any other way? I have a reset button which will reset all the controls in the page causes the flicker too.